# Using partial wakelock and service does not make app run when phone is locked

Tags: android, pyjnius

I am using a partial wake lock and a service in my kivy app so that it can run when I lock the screen. My service makes the phone vibrate every other second when a switch is turned on, while the app attempts to acquire a partial wakelock only when the switch is turned on. This does not seem to work, however, as when I lock my phone, the phone stops vibrating every other second. Here is my main.py.

```
__version__ = "1.0"

import kivy
import plyer
kivy.require('1.0.9')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.lib import osc
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from jnius import autoclass

activityport = 3001
serviceport = 3000



class ActiveSwitch(Switch):
    pass


class VibrateButton(Button):
    def vibrate(self):
            plyer.vibrator.vibrate(3)

class Vibrate(Widget):
    activate = BooleanProperty(True)
    def on_activate(self, instance, value):
            osc.sendMsg('~/kivyinstall/sahil/reply/step3_active/service', [value, ], port=serviceport)


class ActiveApp(App):
    def build(self):
            if platform == 'android':
                    from android import AndroidService
                    service = AndroidService()
                    service.start()
                    self.service = service

            osc.init()
            oscid = osc.listen(ipAddr='127.0.0.1', port=activityport)
            osc.bind(oscid, self.message_callback, '~/kivyinstall/sahil/reply/step3_active')
            Clock.schedule_interval(lambda *x: osc.readQueue(oscid), 0)
            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
            activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
            Context = autoclass('android.content.Context')
            PowerManager = autoclass('android.os.PowerManager')
            power = activity.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)
            global wakelock
            wakelock = power.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 'TAG')

            return Vibrate()

    def message_callback(self, message, *args):
            global switch
            switch = message[2]
            self.function()

    def function(self):
            if switch == 0:
                    wakelock.acquire()
            if switch == 1:
                    wakelock.release()

    def on_pause(self):
            return True

    def on_resume(self):
            pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
         ActiveApp().run()
```

I attempted to use the partial wake lock in order to keep the phone's CPU running while the phone is locked. My guess the reason why the phone stops vibrating when it is locked is that the CPU is shut off when locked, and that the phone uses the CPU to vibrate. Also, when I unlock the phone and re-open the app, the switch is still in the same position as when I left it, since I put the on_pause definition in the code, but the phone is not vibrating any more. This leads me to believe that, for some reason, the code is not acquiring the partial wake lock and the CPU shuts off when the phone is locked. This main.py and the service/main.py are able to communicate the position of the switch successfully. When this main.py gets the message however, wakelock.acquire() does not seem to keep the phone's CPU on.

Does the phone need the CPU on to keep vibrating when locked? If so, then is there another way to keep the CPU on and the phone vibrating after I lock it? Am I using jnius and wakelock.acquire/release correctly?

If the phone doesn't need the CPU to keep vibrating when locked, then what else is causing the phone to stop vibrating when locked, and what do I need to keep the phone vibrating after it is locked?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure you have the WAKE_LOCK permissions set in the buildozer.spec:

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = WAKE_LOCK
```